# Custom className to tagify__input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tagify

I'm using tagify mix with react.
I want to style the input with the className: tagify__input.
however i have 2 tagifies so i cant style directly on the tagify__input className, therefore i want to give a custom class Name to the span.
can you tell me how to do so? because I'm have trouble with it and I'm only able to add class name to the texture.

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.